# Nuxt SSR app crashing on Herokun with no meaningful error

Tags: vue.js, heroku, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js SSR application deployed to Heroku, when I try to visit the deployed app from the URL, I get an error that there's a server error.

When I check the logs, I get this error:

```
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942456+00:00 app[web.1]:  ERROR  Cannot find module 'defu' from '/app'
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942456+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942458+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:89:15)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942459+00:00 app[web.1]:   at node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:77685
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942459+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:/external "defu":1:0)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942460+00:00 app[web.1]:   at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942460+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Module.<anonymous> (server.js:3549:22)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942460+00:00 app[web.1]:   at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942461+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:1176:18)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942461+00:00 app[web.1]:   at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942463+00:00 app[web.1]:   at server.js:118:18
2021-02-25T16:12:24.942463+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:121:10)
```

everything works fine during development and the builds are successful, I just cannot make sense of that error.

I have tried searching the project for the keywords "defu" or "/app" but I'm not getting any results, my app does not have a "/app".

I just don't know what kind of error this is.

Comment: What is your `nuxt.config.js` file looking like ? Did you try to `yarn build` (or `yarn generate`) and then `yarn start` locally to see if you have the same issues ?

Comment: I was able to run `yarn build` and `yarn start` successfully, the server starts, but when I try to visit the app in my browser, it refuses to connect. I'm assuming this part has to do with my laptop and some network restrictions? because I can connect to the deployed app on Heroku.

Comment: I'd fix it locally before going any further. It will be easier to debug locally before handling the issue on Heroku. Try to find why this happens. You should access your built app easily without any network restrictions normally.

Comment: Do you mean when you run yarn start locally, you still can't access the local server?

Comment: Try exposing the server to your local network and then using another device to connect to it. Add this to your `nuxt.config.js` ```server: {  port: 8000, // default: 3000   
 host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost  },```

Comment: Yes @S.Ramjit when I run `yarn start` locally, I cannot access the local server, 

and I already have that config in my `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: But can you access it with another device?

Comment: no I can't  @S.Ramjit

Comment: Hm, try posting an issue on the nuxt GitHub page?

Comment: Side note: View much more verbose logs when using console, as opposed to the Heroku website dashboard. On your local machine use: `heroku logs --tail --app your_app_name`.